Prime react nested TabMenu active index not working
I'm using Next.js(14) with the PrimeReact library to create a navigation component with tab menus. I have a main parent tab (like "Manager," "Reviewer," etc.) and each parent tab has its own set of child tabs (like "New," "Current," "Completed").
The problem I am facing is that when I click on a parent tab, the child tab index is not updating properly. Specifically, even after setting the activeChildIndex to 0 in the handler, the displayed child tab does not reflect the active child tab correctly when I switch between different parent tabs.
Here’s a simplified version of the code:
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { TabMenu } from "primereact/tabmenu";
import { useRouter, usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function Navigation({
  children,
}: Readonly<{ children: React.ReactNode }>) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const getActiveParentIndex = (path: string) => {
    if (path.includes("manager")) return 0;
    if (path.includes("reviewer")) return 1;
    if (path.includes("author")) return 2;
    if (path.includes("admin")) return 3;
    if (path.includes("director")) return 4;
    return -1;
  };

  const getActiveChildIndex = (path: string) => {
    if (path.includes("new")) return 0;
    if (path.includes("current")) return 1;
    if (path.includes("completed")) return 2;
    return -1;
  };

  const [activeParentIndex, setActiveParentIndex] = useState<number>(
    getActiveParentIndex(pathname)
  );

  const [activeChildIndex, setActiveChildIndex] = useState<number>(
    getActiveChildIndex(pathname)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const newActiveParentIndex = getActiveParentIndex(pathname);
    const newActiveChildIndex = getActiveChildIndex(pathname);

    setActiveParentIndex(newActiveParentIndex);
    setActiveChildIndex(newActiveChildIndex);

    console.log("newActiveIndex", newActiveChildIndex);
  }, [pathname]);

 const tabs = [
    {
      label: "Manager",
      items: [
        {
          label: "New Proposal",
          icon: "pi pi-plus",
          command: () => router.push("/manager/new"),
        },
        {
          label: "Current Proposal",
          icon: "pi pi-clock",
          command: () => router.push("/manager/current"),
        },
        {
          label: "Completed Proposal",
          icon: "pi pi-check",
          command: () => router.push("/manager/completed"),
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: "Reviewer",
      items: [
        {
          label: "New Review",
          icon: "pi pi-plus",
          command: () => router.push("/reviewer/new"),
        },
        {
          label: "Current Review",
          icon: "pi pi-clock",
          command: () => router.push("/reviewer/current"),
        },
        {
          label: "Completed Review",
          icon: "pi pi-check",
          command: () => router.push("/reviewer/completed"),
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: "Author",
      items: [
        {
          label: "New Article",
          icon: "pi pi-plus",
          command: () => router.push("/author/new"),
        },
        {
          label: "Current Article",
          icon: "pi pi-clock",
          command: () => router.push("/author/current"),
        },
        {
          label: "Completed Article",
          icon: "pi pi-check",
          command: () => router.push("/author/completed"),
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: "Admin",
      items: [
        {
          label: "New Admin Task",
          icon: "pi pi-plus",
          command: () => router.push("/admin/new"),
        },
        {
          label: "Current Admin Task",
          icon: "pi pi-clock",
          command: () => router.push("/admin/current"),
        },
        {
          label: "Completed Admin Task",
          icon: "pi pi-check",
          command: () => router.push("/admin/completed"),
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: "Director",
      items: [
        {
          label: "New Director Task",
          icon: "pi pi-plus",
          command: () => router.push("/director/new"),
        },
        {
          label: "Current Director Task",
          icon: "pi pi-clock",
          command: () => router.push("/director/current"),
        },
        {
          label: "Completed Director Task",
          icon: "pi pi-check",
          command: () => router.push("/director/completed"),
        },
      ],
    },
  ];


  const handleParentTabChange = (e) => {
    setActiveParentIndex(e.index);
    setActiveChildIndex(0);
    if (tabs[e.index].items.length > 0) {
      tabs[e.index].items[0].command();
    }
  };


  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <TabMenu
        className="mr-auto cursor-pointer px-6"
        model={tabs.map((tab) => ({
          label: tab.label,
          command: () => {
            setActiveParentIndex(tabs.indexOf(tab));
            if (tab.items.length > 0) {
              tab.items[0].command();
            }
          },
        }))}
        onTabChange={handleParentTabChange}
        activeIndex={activeParentIndex}
      />
      <div className="w-full bg-slate-400">{children}</div>
      <div className="flex px-6">
        {activeParentIndex >= 0 && (
          <TabMenu
            model={tabs[activeParentIndex].items}
            activeIndex={activeChildIndex}
          />
        )}
        {activeChildIndex}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

